# bootstrap multi-select adds window horizontal scroll bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

[image]

Boostrap multiselect menu adds window scroll bar when clicked on select button
multiselect in placed in the right most in page, but the expecting the dropdown to auto adjust by position of the button which is not happeing, like the way it happens for pop-over.

`$('.select').multiselect({
                    enableClickableOptGroups: true,
                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    onDropdownShown: function(event) {
            resetDropdownHeight();
        }
                });`

and also tried on add onDropdownShown event as below

```
function resetDropdownHeight(){
            $_dropdownMenu = $('select#testmodal').parent().find('ul');
            console.log(this);
             if ($_dropdownMenu !== null) {
                        $_dropdownMenu.css('left', '55%');
                        $_dropdownMenu.css('right', '5%');                                                                          
                    }


            }
```

below goes the HTML for it

```
 <select multiple="multiple" id="testmodal" class="dropdown-lenthy subtypemultiple version-enableClickableOptGroups-disabled right-dropdown form-control col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 firstdll dropdown-menu-right">

                                                            <option value="1-1">loremu test wright node care must thiis line to read content</option>
                                                            <option value="1-2">loremu test wright node care must thiis line to read content (with Lower/Upper Cap if any)</option>
                                                            <option value="1-3">loremu test wright node care must thiis line to read content (fortnightly)</option>
                                                            <option value="1-4">loremu test wright node care must thiis line to read content(weekly)</option>

                                                    </select>
```

Comment: HTML? HTML? HTML?